# tengo problemas al pasar una cadena como parametro por ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
 <input type="text" name="documento_s" pattern="[VE]{1}[-]{1}[0-9]{6,8}" class="form-control" id="documento" placeholder="V-XXXXXXXX" aria-label="Documento" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="search" onclick="buscar_doc()">Buscar</button>
                        </div>
                           <!-- Iniciamos el segmento de codigo javascript -->
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                              function buscar_doc() {
                                var docu = $('#documento').val();
                                var opc = '';
                                if(docu !==''){
                                  $.ajax({
                                    data:{docu:docu},
                                    dataType: 'html',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url:'busqueda.php'
                                    }).done(function(data){ 
                                      // $('#respuesta').html(data);
                                      $('#nombres').val(data);
```

busqueda.php

```
<?php
include("conexion.php"); //libreria de conexion a la base

$docu = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'docu'); //obtenemos el parametro que viene de ajax
**echo $docu**
```

Cuando muestro $docu si comienza con V-XXXX me trae el objeto completo etiquetas, etc., pero si es solo numeros trabaja bien solo trae los numeros.

Comment: No entendí el problema descrito.

Comment: tengo el ajax por el cual paso un solo parametro un documento, cuando el valor de ese documento es numerico, lo que recibo en busqueda es ese valor, hasta alli bien, pero cuando el valor de ese parametro empieza con una letra, en busqueda se muestra todo el valor del objeto ej: <br> etiquetas, directorios, etc. No entiendo por que?